# Linux: How to round off the date() to nearest interval

Tags: bash, date

I want to round down the minutes to the nearest 15 min interval i.e. 00,15,30,45. I'm currently doing the below:

```
echo $(date +'%Y/%m/%d/%H/')$((($(($(date +'%M') / 15))-0)*15))
```

But at the start of the hour between 1-14 minutes, I get "/2021/11/03/21/0" instead of 00.

Also, I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this. Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
mod=$(( 10#$(date +%M) \% 15 ))
date -d "-${mod} minutes" +%Y/%m/%d/%H/%M
```

- The variable `mod` holds the remainder of the minutes divided by 15.
- Then round down to the nearest 15 minute interval by subtracting `mod`.

**[Edit]**
The manpage of `crontab` says:

> Percent-signs  (%) in the command, unless
> escaped with backslash (), will be changed  into  newline
> characters, and all data after the first % will be sent to
> the command as standard input.

If you want to execute the command within crontab, please modify the command as:

```
mod=$(( 10#$(date +\%M) \% 15 ))
date -d "-${mod} minutes" +\%Y/\%m/\%d/\%H/\%M
```

**[Edit2]**
If you want to embed the code in `crontab` file, please add a line which look like:

```
0 12 * * * username bash -c 'mod=$(( 10#$(date +\%M) \% 15 )); DATEVAR=$(date -d "-${mod} minutes" +\%Y/\%m/\%d/\%H/\%M); write.sh "$DATEVAR"'
```

- Please modify the execution time/date and the username accordingly.
- The default shell to execute crontab command may be `/bin/sh`. Then you will need to explicitly switch it to `/bin/bash` to execute bash commands.
- My apology that a backslash in front of `% 15` (modulo operation) was missing in my previous post.

Comment: This seems like the right approach to me, but why the `10#` prefix? From the manual, "[If base# is omitted, then base 10 is used](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html)".

Comment: @dimo414 Numbers starting with zero are interpreted as octal. Example: `echo $((08))` fails. The `10#` prefix makes it clear that the base is 10.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek thank you for adding the explanation for me! I was just leaving for a while.

Comment: @tshiono This works well! But when I add it to a cron job I get the below error "date: extra operand ‘+%Y/%m/%d/%H/%M’". Can you please let me know how I can have this in a cron/script?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Good point. We need to escape the percent character `%` in the crontab. I've update my answer accordingly. Cheers.

Comment: @tshiono Thank you for providing a solution. Unfortunately, for me, backslash still doesn't work. This is what I'm doing
`mod=$(( 10#$(date +\%M) % 15 )) \n
DATEVAR=date -d "-${mod} minutes" +\%Y/\%m/\%d/\%H/\%M \n
* * * * * write.sh $($DATEVAR)` .  (I've added `\n` just to show newline)
And now I get `date: extra operand ‘+\\%Y/\\%m/\\%d/\\%H/\\%M’`

Comment: Your shown commands have syntax problem. It should look something like `mod=$(( 10#$(date +\%M) % 15 )); DATEVAR=$(date -d "-${mod} minutes" +\%Y/\%m/\%d/\%H/\%M);  * * * * * write.sh "$DATEVAR"`. BTW are you embedding the commands in the crontab? It will be easier to put the commands in a separate file as a standalone  shell script and call it from within the crontab just by its name. If the shell script works well on the terminal, it will be easy to make it work with cron.

Comment: @tshiono That still doesn't work. I get `$(date: command not found` . I agree that a standalone script would be better but we were trying to avoid maintaining an extra script. Thanks for your inputs!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've found that a backslash in front of `% 15`
was missing in my previous post. I've modified my answer considering the
case you want to embed the code in crontab. I agree that maintaining multiple
scripts is a messy task but the coding within the crontab is delicate and
less maintainable, too. Sigh.

Comment: @tshiono  what does the `#` operator do in `10#(date +%M)`

Comment: @whitespace Andrej Podzimek explains it clearly. Please refer to the 2nd comment from the top above. BR.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
min=$(printf "%0.2d" $(( ($(date +'%M') / 15) * 15 )))
echo "$(date +'%Y/%m/%d/%H/')$min"
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
date -d "@$((($(date +%s) + 450) / 900 * 900))"
```

This uses the properties of integer division to “subtract a modulus” and adds half of the desired interval to (almost) mimic a rounding operation.

A bit of extra sub-second rounding precision (for no good reason) can be achieved by taking `%N` (nanoseconds) into account. But it will not matter, because the exact half of the rounding interval (450 seconds) is already aligned with the default epoch resolution (1 second). (If the number of seconds in the desired rounding interval was odd, then the following would increase the time rounding precision.)

```sh
date -d "@$((($(date +%s%N) + 45*10**10) / (9*10**11) * 900))"
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure bash, bash version 4.3 or higher:

```
printf '%(%Y/%m/%d/%H/%M)T\n' "$(( $(printf '%(%s)T') /(15*60)*(15*60) ))"
```

Using GNU `date` (any bash version or POSIX shell):

```
date -d @$(( $(date +%s) /(15*60)*(15*60) )) +%Y/%m/%d/%H/%M
```

- Truncates the current epoch date (seconds since `1970-01-01 00:00:00`) to a 15 minute (900 second) interval, then converts to desired format.
- Retrieves the current date/time *once* only.
- If you build a date/time from two separate date/times, it can be wrong, when a unit ticks over in between.
- The `printf` date-time format string was added in bash 4.2, and was changed in 4.3 to also print the current time, if no input date was given.
- Note that bash arithmetic treats numbers that start with zero as octals, and numbers like `08` and `09` will cause an error (because they are not octal numbers).